# How do I disable my encrypted /home/?

Tags: linux, encryption, ubuntu-9.10, home-directory

I need to disable my encrypted home directory because it prevents me from logging in with my fingerprint scanner when I first boot up.  I'm running kubuntu 9.10.

How do I do this?

Also, how would I revert back to it being encrypted if I decide to not use the fingerprint scanner for initial log in anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How to Remove an Encrypted Private Directory Setup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory#How%20to%20Remove%20an%20Encrypted%20Private%20Directory%20Setup)

However, I don't think you necessarily have to give up the encrypted home directory.

1. Log in
2. Remove  the data files created by the fingerprint reader
3. Unmount the encrypted filesystem by running `ecryptfs-umount-private`
4. Configure the fingerprint reader
5. log out

The fingerprint reader's data files should now reside outside the encrypted part of the home directory.

Answer (score 0):

An actual answer is found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/107410/can-you-unencrypt-remove-encryption-from-a-user-home-folder

To restore the encryption if desired, you do the reverse.